# azure databricks dashboard - can't find 'Subscriber' button

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am reading this official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/user/dashboards/ in order to send the dashboard result visualized charts as email to project stakeholders.

from the official documentation, i should see a Subscriber button in notebook or dashboard like below.
[image]

But i can't see it. i see the share button, but doesn't see the 'Subscriber' button next to 'Share'. Please refer to below screenshot for what I see.

[image]

Anyone know what's the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation that you're referring is for [Databricks SQL](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/user/index.html), but you're working in the notebooks that doesn't have subscribe functionality. If you have SQL dashboard, switch to it using `SQL` item in the dropdown top left of the workspace UI:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the clarification.Is there a way to support notebook sending the dashboard chart result as an attachment via email?

Comment: No, sending by email is supported only for SQL dashboards right now, and I'm not aware about extending this functionality to notebooks. SQL Dashboards are more powerful than notebook's